# Grafana - alerting on n% drops in a gauge over a time period

Tags: prometheus, grafana-alerts

We have a metric like the following

[image]

and we want to alert when there's a 20% drop in value over a 12h period. Our alert is defined as

```
last_over_time(...}[10m] @ end()) / max_over_time(spiceAi_router_Balance{...}[12h])
```

The problem with this is that the 12h window period is fixed, so even after resolving the issue, it keeps coming back and refiring for the next 12h. We cannot silence it because there might be another 20% drop which we would want to get alerted on.

What we would need is for the 12h period to be changed dynamically, for eg based on the last time we resolved an alert.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think what you described is achievable. Maybe(!) you could create some clever logic based on `ALESTS` metric, but it will require quite a bit of trickery.

Comment: @markalex what is `ALESTS` metrics? And more generally, how do people do what we need to do? This seems like such a simple obvious type of query that many people would want to perform. Do people only look for instantaneous drops in metrics then?

Comment: ALERTS is metric that shows active and pending alerts. You can check it out in prometheus' web console or grafana's explorer view. More generally,  I haven't seen alerts with similar requirements, usually they are either for a single moment, or for counters.

Comment: Seems to be a standard thing though. Just found that Datadog calls these change metrics https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/types/metric/